# Bind an amp-state's initial value

Tags: amp-html

I want to initialise an amp-state as follows:

```
<amp-state id="tabs">
  <script type="application/json">
  {
    "selected": "latest"
  }
  </script>
</amp-state>
```

Then have this initialised value shown on first page request:

```
<p [text]="tabs.selected"><p>
```

This doesn't work. The contents of the p tag are only updated when there is a state change. Eg from a button:

```
<button on="tap:AMP.setState({tabs: {selected: 'top'}})">Press me</button>
```

I would like elements on the page to reflect the initialised state before further user interaction.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/powlo/pen/VMpVRm/?editors=1000

Comment: I know it is not evaluated on page load, but did you find a work around to your problem? Can you share code of how you did it? I'm struggling with the same problem.

Comment: See my comment on the accepted answer, you have provided initial vanilla html attributes or content. So <p [text]="tabs.selected">Initial content<p>. Something like that (not verified).

Comment: Indeed powlo, think..if your initial value is "latest", why just don't do
`<p [text]="tabs.selected">latest<p>` ? The whole point of bind is for LATER interaction, so it can not obstruct the page initial load.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

amp-bind expressions are not evaluated on page load. This is intentional to avoid layout jumps on page load. If you want to dynamically initialize elements on page load, you need to use the amp-list extension (even if it is only a single element).

Comment: Basically, you should always provide a meaningful attribute, as well as the bound attribute. Eg text="1" [text]="somestate.somevar"